# What is .Net Socket.Handle equivalent for java

Tags: java, sockets

In java is there any functionality equivalent to below c# functionality.

```
Socket.Handle
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.handle(v=vs.110).aspx

I have searched on internet and also I checked the properties of java.net.Socket but I could not extract similar thing. Any information is appreciated.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't think there is any equivalent to this. What is your use-case? There is probably a way to achieve the same thing is Java just using different mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you basically need `socket.getImpl().getFileDescriptor().fd`. None of these methods/fields are public, leaving [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) as your only option:

```
static int getHandle(Socket socket) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    Method getImpl = Socket.class.getDeclaredMethod("getImpl");
    getImpl.setAccessible(true);
    SocketImpl impl = (SocketImpl) getImpl.invoke(socket);
    Method getFileDescriptor = SocketImpl.class.getDeclaredMethod("getFileDescriptor");
    getFileDescriptor.setAccessible(true);
    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = (FileDescriptor) getFileDescriptor.invoke(impl);
    Field fd = FileDescriptor.class.getDeclaredField("fd");
    fd.setAccessible(true);
    return (int) fd.get(fileDescriptor);
}
```

As of Java 9, this comes with a bunch of warnings:

> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
>   ...
>   WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

As a conclusion, (plain) Java is probably not the right tool for this requirement.